# How to export and run iOS project from Kony Visualizer to Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, temenos-quantum

I am not used to work with kony platform and I have created simple app but I want to export it and run it as native iOS `.xcocdeproj`.

Answer (score 0):

Kony Visualizer gives you different ways of building and viewing your app, depending on your needs. In Kony Visualizer Enterprise, you can build your app either from the Product menu, or from a command line. And you can view your built app either by previewing it on a mobile device, or by using device emulators and simulators that you configure. Please refer to this [docs link](https://docs.kony.com/konylibrary/visualizer/visualizer_user_guide/Default.htm#BuildAnAppForiOS.htm) to build for iOS using Kony Visualizer.

Comment: can you describe the process of emulators and simulators configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Please do this below steps.

1. once Kar file was build. go to your visualizer installation folder and go to plugins and then you can find com.kony.ios_8.2.28.v201811051627.jar  file if you are using 8.2.28 version just for example.
2. Copy above file and rename it as zip file and unzip it.
3. once unzip was done inside you can find another zip file please unzip. ( ex: 8.2.28.zip)
4. you can see folder called VMAppWithKonylib.
5. now go open command-line tool and go to VMAppWithKonylib location.
6. now go to gen folder location inside your commandline. gen folder will inside VMAppWithKonylib.
   7.now run this command - perl extract.pl konyappiphone.KAR
7. once extract done now go to VMAppWithKonylib and open project in xcode.

let me know if you are facing any more issues.

Comment: I have tried and open project in xcode but when I tried to run it gave me an error : "error: /Users/alpeshpatel/KonyEnterPrise/KonyVisualizerEnterprise8.4.0.0/Kony_Visualizer_Enterprise/plugins/com.kony.ios_8.4.0.v201901181124 copy/VMAppWithKonylib/UserWidgetJSScripts: No such file or directory"

Comment: Ok can you give me full error log to check and help you.

Comment: I had opened project in xcode as per your mentioned steps but when my question is could I run that project in xcode? because when I tried to run in xcode I got an error - "error: /Users/alpeshpatel/KonyEnterPrise/KonyVisualizerEnterprise8.4.0.0/Kony_Visualizer_Enterprise/plugins/com.kony.ios_8.4.0.v201901181124 copy/VMAppWithKonylib/UserWidgetJSScripts: No such file or directory".